# How do I add a small additional package to a class library in Java?

Tags: java, classpath

I have a package called org.mine.level1.level2
I want to add a package called org.mine.helper with a class called org.mine.helper.Calc

So I went to java/org/mine where the directory 'level1' already is and created 'helper'. Then I created Calc.java and put a class in it. I also added usage of the class to org.mine.level1.level2 code (a couple of java files in there).

When javac compiled the modified level2 code it said that the org.mine.helper.Calc file didn't exist.

I looked at the existing tree and there was a build.xml file which said

```
<property name="src" location="java" />
```

which is the parent of the org directory. So it seemed like whatever is reading build.xml doesn't need to know the names of all the java files. That indicated to me I could add a directory at will and it would just be incorporated.

In tutorials that have multiple packages they always run javac on each file, cause the class files to go in some directory and put that in a class path. I guessed that build.xml is defining all that and I could just add my stuff.

What can I do to get my new java code compiled for the benefit of the places I use it?

Error messages:

```
org/mine/level1/level2/Usage.java:8: error: package org.mine.helper does not exist
    import org.mine.helper.Calc;
                          ^
org/mine/level1/level2/Usage.java:74: error: package org.mine.helper does not exist
    org.mine.helper.Calc.compute();
```

Comment: You say `it said that the org.mine.helper.Calc file didn't exist` - but it didn't.  It's saying that the package (ie the directory)  `org/mine/helper` doesn't exist.   Somehow, you have not created that 'helper' directory in the right place.

Comment: Also bear in mind that Java is case sensitive, and if your OS filesystem is too, you'll have a problem if the directory name is HELPER instead of helper.

Comment: @racraman I think after looking at the compile logs MUCH more closely that I made the wrong org/mine/helper directory with respect to the organization of the code. There are plenty of 'java/org/mine' directories, and that's just the tip of the iceberg. So java/org/mine/helper exists but not where it should exist.

Comment: @racraman Or else it's a matter for the classpath, but it's a much more complex situation than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> So I went to java/org/mine where the directory 'level1' already is and created 'helper'. Then I created Calc.java and put a class in it.

But if you wanted to add a source file to the package `org.mine.helper`, then you should have gone to `org/mine/helper`, and created `Calc.java` there.  So, you should either make this change, or, if you want to refer to the `Calc` class as it currently is located, then use this import statement:

```
import org.mine.helper.level1.Calc;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a misreading of what you quoted. Translating "I went to java/org/mine" to gives `cd something/java/org/mine` Translating "where the directory 'level1' aready is" means that "ls" would show 'level1' is there. Translating "created 'helper' would mean at that command prompt, typing `mkdir helper` Translating "Then I created Calc.java and put a class in it" would mean that I saved Calc.java in helper. After all that's what I said I wanted to do.